# OpenCV program works in MacOS terminal but not IDLE

Tags: python, opencv, python-import, python-idle

This is my first time using OpenCV and I'm having some difficulties. I just made a simple program to see if it was imported correctly:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print("hi")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap.isOpened())
print("hi")
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this file on the MacOS terminal, it works fine and opens up the video window, but when I run this file with IDLE nothing happens. No errors or warnings, the first "hi" prints but nothing else and the program ends. It's like as soon as I try to use cv2 directly after the first "hi", the program just ends. I believe I'm using the same version of python in both my terminal and IDLE, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling OpenCV using pip. Did I not install OpenCV correctly to be using with IDLE? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Not sure if this is causing any problems, but when I first ran it from IDLE, it had a few "Python quit unexpectedly" windows before I tried it in terminal. When I tried it there, it asked for access to my computer's webcam. Since then, the "Python quit unexpectedly" windows haven't showed up when I tried IDLE, so maybe it just needs access to my camera? I don't see an option for that in my Mac settings though, there's no IDLE app option to give access to.

Comment: Does it work if you start IDLE _from the terminal_? If it's a problem that happens only when you don't have environment variables &c set by your shell dotfiles, that gives us a place to look.

Comment: That's so weird, it worked when I started IDLE from the terminal! Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: See my first comment ("If it's a problem that happens only when you don't have environment variables &c set by your shell dotfiles") -- the details depend a little based on which operating system you're on (for example, on MacOS it's launchd that controls the environment for things you start from the GUI, IIRC), but in general your shell dotfiles are only guaranteed to run when you start things from a shell. (It didn't used to be that way on UNIXlike systems -- you used to have the GUI started from a login shell so your `.profile` or equivalent was run -- but that was rather a long time ago).

Comment: Oh alright! So would there be anything I could do to set those environment variables, or am I somewhat screwed since they're not guaranteed to run? I'm on MacOS

Comment: A good place to start is to compare `os.environ` between the working and broken environments, and set variables from the working environment into the broken one one-by-one until you find out which one, when set, solves the problem. The set of environment variables isn't the _only_ possible problem, but it's by far the most likely one.

Comment: Once you've figured out which variable needs to be set, you might see [Setting environment variables in OS X for GUI applications](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Maybe also check that it's the same Python executable being used in both cases -- you can check that by comparing `sys.executable`

Comment: You can check if access to the camera is causing issues by commenting out all the video stuff and generating a random image with `frame = np.random.randint(0,256,(480,640,3), dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: It's possible that IDLE intercepts all your keystrokes and won't let `cv2.imshow()` see them when running under IDLE. Jupyter Lab does that, for example.

Comment: I tried Mark's suggestion by commenting out the video stuff and generating a random image, and the window opened and is showing a frame with what looks like tv static! Would that mean that it might be a problem with camera access?

Comment: The image is random static, I could have suggested `frame = np.full((480, 640, 3), [255, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)` for a solid blue image.

Comment: It does seem like it might be camera access related. The camera permission popup window might be behind IDLE or your Terminal window. Sorry, I don't use IDLE and it's late here - I may take a look tomorrow.

Comment: IDLE does not need access to the camera, however, the python running it does, and you seem to have solved that when you ran cv2 with python from the terminal.

Comment: When you run code with IDLE, the IDLE Shell become the active window that receives keystrokes so one can respond to an input('prompt') or enter a new statement at '>>>' when your code finishes.  Opening a new program with a window that expects keystrokes usually makes the new window the active window.  If cv2.imshow() does not make the user process running cv2 the key input process, one might have to click on it.  Details depend on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

Snippet:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap.isOpened())

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Or:

snippet:

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

rval, frame = vc.read()

while True:

  if frame is not None:   
     cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
  rval, frame = vc.read()

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break
```

Comment: Nothing happened for either of those, the shell just restarts after a second or two when I try to run those.